# How to navigate through file tree in VS Code using vscodevim?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to improve my skill with using the vim extension on vscode, and I would like to ask if it is possible to navigate through the file tree with it.

Here is what I would want to do:

1. Jump from my window to file tree.
2. Move up/down
3. Open a specific file (eg. search index.jsx and open it)
4. Delete a file
5. Add a new file/folder in the tree
6. Open a file that has a specific class/function

If there is a better document for this, I would be glad to explore more :)

[image]

Comment: How are you trying to improve your vim skills, if you use vscode? I thought I need to use vim to improve vim skills.

Comment: I love using vim while programming, It is easy for me to navigate through my code and edit. It has many helpful functions that I cannot get in other editors and it is customizable.
So, that's why I want to learn more about navigating through file trees.

Comment: I am confused. You say, you use VS Code. How is it connected to vim?

Comment: `VScode / View / Command Palette..` is an essential entry. You can learn the editor features by typing `Help: Welcome` and find `Learn` section which helps solve most of your concerns.

Comment: @DracoAter There is a vim extension for vscode that is like an emulator and you have the same keybinds etc

Comment: That's correct @Costa, Thanks for the edit too :)
Also if you have some tips regarding my question, I will appreciate it.

Comment: How can I make vscode project directory look like yours with a visible tree structure instead of simple indentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VSCodeVim provides only text editing and navigation commands like *}*, *dd*, *p* and so on. Moreover, [None of the native Visual Studio Code ctrl (e.g. ctrl+f, ctrl+v) commands work.](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim) The only way to use VSCode commands is turn off vim extension: ctrl + P > Toggle Vim Mode.